# Make \sections in book class start on the right (odd pages)

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, books

I'm using the book documentclass, but I use `\section` instead of `\chapter` to structure it.

Is it possible to make the sections start on the right (odd pages)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Redefine `\section` to always issue `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\let\oldsection\section% Store \section in \oldsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}% Prepend new \section with \cleardoublepage
```

The above assumes you're using a `twoside` document class option and/or `openright`.

Comment: I'm currently not using `twoside` or `openright`, but it still seems to work.  Do I need to add one of those options?

Comment: @WeierstrassSauce: Your documentclass may load this by default (like `book`). What are you using?

Comment: Oh, yes, I am using `book` so it loads `twoside` by default, right.  Thanks so much!